# Слайдер изображений с возможностью комментирования изображений?

Tags: jquery, gallery, слайдер

Услышал от знакомого, что есть слайдер или галерея, с возможностью комментирования изображений, при условии, что комментатор имеет регистрацию на фейсбук. Галерея, как я понял на основе fancybox.  Никогда не видел ничего подобного, интересно было бы увидеть подобную реализацию. Кто знает, скиньте ссылку пожалуйста, глянуть на подобное.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В галерее `lightgallery.js` есть возможность подключать комментарии как раз с привязкой к аккаунту facebook. Реализуется это с помощью скрипта от Facebook. Код самого простого исполнения - ниже + [GitHub](https://github.com/saszami/saszami.github.io/tree/master/comment) и [сама страничка](https://saszami.github.io/comment/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lightgallery.js@1.0.1/dist/css/lg-fb-comment-box.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lightgallery.js@1.0.1/dist/css/lightgallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
 <!--Facebook script-->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {

      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;

      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";

      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
  <!-- Gallery -->
  <div id="lightgallery">
    <a href="https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/09/23a6461b9b8a8cb0a25e046c26053cf6.jpg" data-sub-html='<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://saszami.github.io/stackOverflow/#lg=1&slide=0" data-width="400" data-numposts="5"></div>'>
      <img src="https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/thumbs/2017/09/23a6461b9b8a8cb0a25e046c26053cf6.png" />
    </a>

    <a href="https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/09/6345b81bd20f2f9993fbe64a5a461dd5.jpg" data-sub-html='<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://saszami.github.io/stackOverflow/#lg=1&slide=1" data-width="400" data-numposts="5"></div>'>
      <img src="https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/thumbs/2017/09/6345b81bd20f2f9993fbe64a5a461dd5.png" />
    </a>
  </div>


  <!--jQuery-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--lightgallery js-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lightgallery.js@1.0.1/dist/js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
 <!--lightgallery hash plugin-->
  <script src="js/lg-hash.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // lightgallery commentbox

  var commentBox = document.getElementById('lightgallery');

lightGallery(commentBox, {
  appendSubHtmlTo: '.lg-item',
  addClass: 'fb-comments',
  download: false,
  enableDrag: false,
  enableSwipe: false
});

commentBox.addEventListener('onAfterSlide', function(event) {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.lg-outer .lg-item');
  if (!items[event.detail.index].getAttribute('data-fb')) {
    try {
      items[event.detail.index].setAttribute('data-fb', 'loaded');
      FB.XFBML.parse();
    } catch (err) {
      window.addEventListener('fbAsyncInit', function() {
        items[event.detail.index].setAttribute('data-fb', 'loaded');
        FB.XFBML.parse();
      });
    }
  }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Cheg, ошибочка вышла :) Извиняюсь. Там и слайдер есть:0

Comment: Ответ в виде ссылке неприемлем. В случае удаления страницы по ссылке данный ответ будет бесполезен другим посетителям. Постарайтесь привести пример работы плагина, который вы предлагаете

Comment: @Cheg как корректно для данного ресурса привести пример работы плагина, если реализация и пример оного в рамках названной галереи даны в документации, и пример этот достаточно обширен?

Comment: Это с легкость можно сделать, воспользовавшись кнопкой "фрагмент кода" и добавив в него все необходимые файлы + код